# Div alignment not working properly

Tags: css, html

**css**

```
#content2
    {
    clear:both;
    width:1024px;
    height:auto;
        position:relative;
    }
    #content2 div:first-child
    {
    background:#E4ECF7;
    width:445px;
    height:25px;
    margin:15px 0px 0px 223px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #E0DCD1;
    padding:5px 0px 0px 5px;
    position:absolute;
    }
    #content2 div:last-child
    {
    width:1024px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid #E0DCD1;
    clear:both;
    }
```

**Html**

```
<div id="content2">
<div>content</div>
<div>content</div>
</div>
```

**Result**

**div1**  is showing inside **div2**

**I need**

```
div1  then
div2
```

Please help me.

Comment: Remove `position:absolute;` from both divs style. Divs will be positioned like you need by default without any styles

Comment: inside div 2 style, write clear: both;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why using position absolute,no need for clear property for last-child

```
#content2
{
clear:both;
width:1024px;
height:auto;
    position:relative;
}
#content2 div:first-child
{
background:#E4ECF7;
width:445px;
height:25px;
margin:15px 0px 0px 223px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
border-radius:5px;
border:1px solid #E0DCD1;
padding:5px 0px 0px 5px;
/*position:absolute;*/
}
#content2 div:last-child
{
width:1024px;
height:200px;
/*position:absolute;*/
border:1px solid #E0DCD1;
/*clear:both;*/
}
```

div are cleared by default unless after using float property

Answer (score 1):

remove position absolute from both child divs...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Position: absolute;` specify the margin for both div's.

eg:

```
#content2 div:last-child
    {
    width:1024px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top: xxx; /* specify the top margin */
    border:1px solid #E0DCD1;
    clear:both;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you are looking like this :- http://tinkerbin.com/3qRLgscO

Actually you made **CSS** bit of complicated for yourself.You can get your desired results through very simple CSS without using of `positioning`.

And if we are using `float` than we should use the `clear` for clearing the floated div's otherwise no need to use the `clear` property.

Here is the simple code of yours i have some simple changes in your **CSS**.....

**HTML**

```
<div id="content2">
<div>div1</div>
<div>div2</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#content2 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 1024px;
}
#content2 div:first-child {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E4ECF7;
    height: 45px;
}

#content2 div:last-child {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 yellow;
    border: 1px solid #E0DCD1;
    height: 45px;
}
```

I hope this will help you........

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following properties in your div class.

```
float:left
clear:right;
```